# (Excel add-in) When setting a large number to Range.value, the resulting number in the spreadsheet is different

Tags: excel, range, add-in, office-js

When setting a large number as the value for a Range (cell), the number that is written to the spreadsheet is different than the original number. E.g.

If I set 42300000000, the number in excel becomes -649672960. This doesn't happen with smaller numbers

I tested it with the basic project sample from Visual Studio. Just replaced the original loadSampleData function with:

```
function loadSampleData() {

     var values = [
                    [4230, 42300, 423000],
                    [4230000, 42300000, 423000000],
                    [4230000000, 42300000000, 423000000000]
    ];

    // Run a batch operation against the Excel object model
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        // Create a proxy object for the active sheet
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        // Queue a command to write the sample data to the worksheet
        sheet.getRange("B3:D5").values = values;

        // Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
        return ctx.sync();
    })
    .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

When I run the add-in, I get this in Excel:

```
4230         42300      423000
4230000      42300000   423000000
-64967296   -649672960  2093204992
```

Is this some kind of overflow? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I confirm this Bug in 1704 (8017.1000) any large 10 digit or greater number fails.

Comment: Let me pass this on to the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug.

The problem seems to be in the JSON parser that we are using to deserialize the incoming request. It incorrectly assumes that any integer number fits in `int32_t`. The correct behavior would be to parse such large values as `double` despite of the fact that they are integers.

Since this isn't Excel code, a fix may take a long time.

Unfortunately, appending `.0` or `E0` at the end of these literals, doesn't drive the parser to parse these literals as `double`. As **Charles Williams** pointed out, enclosing the literals in single or double quotes serves your purpose [for some unknown reason].

I haven't been able to find a more deterministic work around. Other suggestions will be welcome.

Zlatko

Comment: 9876543210.0 fails but 9876543210.9 works - this is a Cat 1 bug IMHO             let range = sheet.getRange("C3");
            range.values = [[ 9876543210.0 ]];

Comment: Ah, @CharlesWilliams, you are correct. I apologize. Let me figure some decent workaround.

Answer (score 1):

When I explore this bug I get the following results

- 9876543210 and 9876543210.0 give 1286608618 - fail
- 9876543210.9 gives 9876543210.9 - works
- '9876543210' and "9876543210" - do not result in a string (I would consider that a bug but maybe this is just a JS type confusion nasty) but give
  9876543210 as a number (so a possible hack bypass to the original bug)
- "'9876543210" gives '9876543210 which excel recognises as a string -
  correct

using the following code with 1704.8017.1000

```
async function setValue() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

            let range = sheet.getRange("C3");
            range.values = [[ 9876543210.0 ]];
            range.format.autofitColumns();

            await context.sync();
        });

        console.log("Done!");
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```